# Convert line separated data into excel data from pdf

Tags: excel, pdf

I have a pdf which has word meanings in the following format:

```
word1     meaning1
_____________________
word2     meaning2 in 
          multiple lines.
_____________________
word3     meaning3
_____________________
```

I want to store this information in Excel as

```
| column1  | column2                     |
+----------+-----------------------------+
| word1    | meaning1                    |
| words2   | meaning2 in multiple lines. |
| word3    | meaning3                    |
```

For each pair, I want only one cell per word and meaning. I tried this converting to Excel via online tools but its not getting identified correctly. Copy pasting is not working because multiple lines of pdf become multiple lines in excel and merging(via macro) them with a full stop as delimiter fails as some meanings have full stops inside them. Is there any easy way to achieve it?

Update screenshot of Excel needed:

[image]

Comment: I am not getting your exact Excel format, Can you please show some sort of Screenshot?

Comment: updated with screenshot